# TypeError: Cannot create property 'data' on string

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I have a Node.js blog API. Currently I post a JSON object containing a title and content using Insomnia. I'd now like to include an image in my post.

My Json looks like this:

```
    {
        "post": {
            "title": "My title",
            "content": "This content",
            "image": "/path/to/image.jpg"
        }
    }
```

My `addPost` function contains:

```js
    newPost.image.data = fs.readFileSync(newPost.image);
    newPost.image.contentType = 'image/jpeg';

    // Let's sanitize inputs
    newPost.title = sanitizeHtml(newPost.title);
    newPost.content = sanitizeHtml(newPost.content);
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'data' on string '/path/to/image.jpg'

I think this because `newPost.image.data` expects an object but `fs.readFileSync(newPost.image)` is a string. I don't know how to deal with this though. Can anybody offer any suggestions?

**Full addPost function:**

**Full addPost code:**

```
PostController.addPost = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        if (!req.body.post.title || !req.body.post.content) {
            res.status(403).end();
        }

        const newPost = new Post(req.body.post);

        newPost.image = {};
        newPost.image.data = fs.readFileSync(newPost.image);
        newPost.image.type = 'image/jpeg';

        // Let's sanitize inputs
        newPost.title = sanitizeHtml(newPost.title);
        newPost.content = sanitizeHtml(newPost.content);

        newPost.slug = slug(newPost.title.toLowerCase(), { lowercase: true });
        newPost.cuid = cuid();

        newPost.save((err, saved) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.json({ post: saved });
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

**Post**

```js
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const postSchema = new Schema({
        title: { type: 'String', required: true },
        content: { type: 'String', required: true },
        image: { data: Buffer, type: 'String', required: true }, //added when trying to get the image to post
        slug: { type: 'String', required: true },
        cuid: { type: 'String', required: true },
        dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
});

    let Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

    export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `newPost.image = {}` as empty object and then assign the value

```js
newPost.image.data = fs.readFileSync(newPost.image);
newPost.image.contentType = 'image/jpeg';
```

Comment: addPost function code added. Apologies if you get an alert saying it was added to your answer. I initially put it in there be mistake.

Comment: What's your `const newPost = new Post(req.body.post);`, here `Post` function Doing ? Share the code of the same. This should not happen since `newPost.image = {};` is already being assigned to new Object.

Comment: Apologies for the delay @Ankur Anand. Code for Post has been added to the original question. Please note I only added the line `image: { data: Buffer, type: 'String', required: true },` when trying to get the image upload working.